# Entity Framework will not load ALL my associations when using a database-first approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-relationship

I created a DB-model in Microsoft Access 2013 in which I have rules and associations made. I there-after transfered this DB to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with full success, the associations are all still there and seem to be exactly the way I want them to be.

You'll have to excuse me for removing so many parts of it, however the general idea should be clear even with me "censoring" it; This is how the database diagram looks in SQL Server 2012:
http://i44.tinypic.com/ay51dy.png

However... I'm using Visual studio 2012 with Entity Framework Version 6.0, and with a database-first approach. The results are not what I expected, as my .edmx-file will NOT transfer all the associations which already exist and can be seen even from SQL Server. All the tables are transfered just fine, it's purely the associations which only 1/4 of them all are actually transfered and shown, manually adding them all eventually ends up with the last one not wanting to work no matter how much I try (Error 111).

To make it as simple as possible; Using the database-first approach, my person-table will only have one association autogenerated, but as you can see above it should have 10 more. This happens all around, certain associations are autocreated and others seems to just be dismissed for no apparent reason.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is causing this issue, how to approach it? I'd rather not start with modeling everything up again directly into Visual Studios designer and then make it create the DB with associations and such.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the "Output" panel in Visual Studio should have a bunch of crud in it after generating code from the database. Are there any errors or warnings that appear in this output?

Comment: After using the Database-first approach (meaning, having it modulate it in edmx), there are no errors shown in the output-panel. I've also opened up the .edmx-file and searched for "error" with 0 success, I just can't figure out why it won't load all the associations instead of so very few of them.

Comment: Well I gave up trying to have it all autogenerated, I added the remaining associations manually and those that just wouldn't be added even manually, I left out.